# Excel vba set varible to workbook level named range

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook level named range "Lookup" that is 2 columns. It will be used as find/replace pairs.  When I try to set a range variable to the named range, I get a type mismatch error. How do you set a variable to a workbook level named range?

```
Sub UpdateResults()
Dim rngLookup As Range, rngUpdate As Range, sFrom As String, sTo As String, iLookupRowCount As Long, iRow As Long
Set rngLookup = ActiveWorkbook.Names("Lookup")
If rngLookup Is Nothing Then GoTo ExitSub

Set rngUpdate = ActiveWorkbook.Names("Resource_File")
If rngUpdate Is Nothing Then GoTo ExitSub

iLookupRowCount = rngLookup.Rows.Count
If iLookupRowCount < 1 Then GoTo ExitSub

For iRow = 1 To iLookupRowCount
    sFrom = rngLookup.Cells(iRow, 1)
    sTo = rngLookup.Cells(iRow, 2)
Debug.Print sFrom
Debug.Print sTo
Next iRow


Exit Sub
ExitSub:
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to set a Name object to a Range object.

Use

```
Set rngLookup = ActiveWorkbook.Names("Lookup").RefersToRange
```

Check this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834918.aspx

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Still don't understand why @Limak approach works. The range object doesn't apply to workbooks, so how can it be used to refer to workbook level named ranges? Seems to me that it would only work with sheet level names....

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
Set rngLookup = Range("Lookup")
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought about using that but I thought that I could only refer to sheet level names that way. When you autolist members for Activeworkbook, there is no "Range".